# Is it possible to use System V shared memory with POSIX semaphores?

Tags: posix, semaphore, shared-memory

I have a two programs that communicate using System V shared memory.

Both programs work as they should, but I would like to add named semaphores to avoid race conditions.

I have tried the following:

```
sem_t *sem = sem_open("/semaphorename", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);

if(sem == SEM_FAILED){
    sem = sem_open("/semaphorename", 0);
}

while(1){
    /*get input from user */
    sem_wait(sem);
    /* write to shared memory. If QUIT is entered, break from while loop */
    sem_post(sem);
}
sem_close(sem);
sem_unlink("/semaphorename");
```

Without the semaphores, the programs work, but with them, nothing is written to shared memory. What am I doing wrong and is it even possible to use these semaphores when I am using System V shared memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the initial value of the semaphore is 0, `sem_wait()` will wait forever until someone does `sem_post()`. So initialise the semaphore with a single `sem_post()` in only one of the programs.